# How to add html elements (buttons, links etc) at the corner of the page or at the center?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a Manager's page, and I want to add a **LOG-OUT** button on the **right** of the page.

I know how to add buttons one by one, for example:

[image]

Here is the code for the above page:

```
<!-- Bank manager's permissions -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bank Manager's Transactions Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="title">
      <tr><th>Manager's Transactions Page</th></tr>
    </table>

    <h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
    <h1>
    Please choose one of the following options
    </h1>

    <!-- The followings are Manager's permissions -->

    <fieldset>
      <legend>To get a list of all the employees at the bank</legend> 
      <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
        <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
      </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>To get a list of all the clients at the bank</legend> 
      <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
        <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
      </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>To get a list of all the overdraft clients at the bank</legend> 
      <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
        <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
      </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>To get the number of overdraft clients at the bank</legend> 
      <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
        <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
      </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>To get a full financial report for the current month</legend> 
      <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
        <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
      </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>To get a full financial report for a specific date</legend> 
      <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
        <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
      </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

How can I add a button in one of the corners of a JSP file?

Regards

Comment: This is more of an html/css question rather than a question related to JSP. You can use a `<div>` or `<span>` tag around the button and then use CSS's position properties on the `<div>` or `<span>`.

Comment: you need the logout button in right side of the page corner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as writing a `css` file.
First write a `css`. something like this: `bar.css`

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.bar
{
 width:40px;
}

#right
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    background:#06F;
}
```

Then have these in your `jsp` file:

```
<link href="bar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And for the link for logging out:

```
<div id ="right" class="bar">
<!-- Your Link to Log out -->
</div>
```

It is just an example. This example would put your `link` to the right. Set your parameters anything, to have your `log out link` in the place you like. You might also want to put it at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

style.css

```
#logout
{
float:right;
margin-right:20px;
height:5px;
}
```

in the page

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="logout"><button>Your text</button></div>
```

Comment: Please never give answers with inline CSS. It might be easier than using an external stylesheet, but it makes for messy HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head><title>Bank Manager's Transactions Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
                body,html
                {
                    margin:0;
                }
               #logout
                {
                    float:right;
                }​
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>

<!-- Logout link, instead of using anchor tag you can replace it with button tag ...... -->

            <div id="logout">
                   <a href="logoutPage">LogOut</a>  
            </div> 

<!-- if you chose button tag, you remove the div and you can directly put stylesheet using button id -->

            <table class="title">
              <tr><th>Manager's Transactions Page</th></tr>
            </table>
            <h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
            <h1>
            Please choose one of the following options
            </h1>

            <!-- The followings are Manager's permissions -->

            <fieldset>
              <legend>To get a list of all the employees at the bank</legend> 
              <form action="blablabla">     <!-- THAT ONE forwards to a servlet that's called Admin1.java -->
                <a href="adminAdds1">Press here to continue</a>  
              </form>
            </fieldset>        

        <!-- code continues...... -->

        </body>​
    </html>
```